# Convert raw MySQL to Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Can someone help me with converting this SQL-query to Eloquent?

```sql
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount
FROM recurrings
WHERE space_id = 1 
    AND YEAR(starts_on) <= 2019 
    AND MONTH(starts_on) <= 08
    AND ((YEAR(ends_on) >= 2019 AND MONTH(ends_on) >= 08) OR ends_on IS NULL)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's a very odd condition. it's not invalid. but strange that we would want to exclude a `starts_on` value of `2018-09-01`. i'm a bit puzzled why we only allow `starts_on` month values before September, even if the year is before 2019.  Seems like what we might actually be intending to express here is the condition `starts_on < '2019-09-01'` but that's just a guess. (The condition in the query may be exactly what's intended. It's just an odd condition.)

Comment: See the function monthlyRecurrings at the bottom: https://github.com/range-of-motion/budget/blob/master/app/Space.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model for the table `recurrings` is called `Recurring`:

```php
# App\Recurring.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recurring extends Model
{
    // This table name follows the Laravel naming convention so this line isn't necessary.
    // This is just to be explicit. Or if you want to give the model a different name.
    // https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models
    protected $table = 'recurrings';
    // Since you're using dates, it's best to mutate them into Carbon objects.
    // It will make dealing with them easier when using php.
    // https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators
    protected $dates = ['starts_on', 'ends_on'];
}
```

```php
$recurrings = Recurring::selectRaw('SUM(amount)')      // SELECT SUM(amount) FROM recurrings
    ->where('space_id', 1)                             // WHERE space_id = 1
    ->whereYear('starts_on', '<=', '2019')             // AND YEAR(starts_on) <= 2019
    ->whereMonth('starts_on', '<=', '08')              // AND MONTH(starts_on) <= 08
    ->where(function($q1) {                            // AND (
        $q1->where(function($q2) {                     //       (
               $q2->whereYear('ends_on', '>=', '2019') //         YEAR(ends_on) >= 2019
                  ->whereMonth('ends_on', '>=', '08'); //         AND MONTH(ends_on) >= 08
           })                                          //       )
           ->orWhereNull('ends_on');                   //       OR ends_on IS NULL
    })->get();                                         // )
```

If you do not have a model, use `DB::table('recurrings')->...` instead of `Recurring::...`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Using the Query Builder's `connection` and `toSql()` method, I was able to test that this query returns what you asked for in the console.

```sh
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.4 — cli) by Justin Hileman

\DB::connection('mysql')->table('recurrings')->selectRaw('SUM(amount)')->where('space_id', 1)->whereYear('starts_on', '<=', '2019')->whereMonth('starts_on', '<=', '08')->where(fun
ction($q1) { $q1->where(function($q2) { $q2->whereYear('ends_on', '>=', '2019')->whereMonth('ends_on', '>=', '08'); })->orWhereNull('ends_on'); })->toSql();
=> "select SUM(amount) from `recurrings` where `space_id` = ? and year(`starts_on`) <= ? and month(`starts_on`) <= ? and ((year(`ends_on`) >= ? and month(`ends_on`) >= ?) or `ends_on`
 is null)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
use AppRecurring;
    function mySum(Recurring $recurring){

    $data['amount']=$recurring::sum('amount')
    ->where('space_id',1)
    ->whereYear('starts_on','<=','2019')
    ->whereMonth('start_on','<=','08')
    ->whereYear('ends_on','>=','2019')
    ->whereMonth('ends_on','>=','08')
    ->orWhereNull('ends_on')
    ->get();
    }
```

Comment: please contextualize more your answer